# Python requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout

Tags: python, python-requests, vk

I want to save images from vk's groups posts. But requests give me this mistake

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sun1-95.userapi.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /impg/DKsod3pGDta5b1qODuCmR1u_wiTvWWO33PzrjA/m43mpFGA5qA.jpg?size=510x629&quality=95&sign=364cbe4ad52971f2f26e3f89919aba83&c_uniq_tag=L1vm9aX43cGpZQk5gSG60gH2874jU-KM4sTaPyEiEwQ&type=album (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F647F59E90>, 'Connection to sun1-95.userapi.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
```

I tried to fix it using the following code

```
    connect_loop = True
while connect_loop:
    try:
        res = requests.get(url, timeout=3)
        connect_loop = False
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:  # любая ошибка requests
        print('ConnectionError')
        continue
```

After few minutes working, I get lots of

Comment: After few minutes working, I get lots of ConnectionError

Comment: What is the URL? Also, try *except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:* and then *print(e)* which may give you a better idea about what's really happening

Comment: well, it seems like after a while the server is denying connections. Maybe worth checking if the server has some kind of limits on requests or requests frequency you can make.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda I used the same code two months ago and it worked very well even "without" while and "try/except"

Comment: @Vadim, in 2 months a lot of things can change. If your code used to work back then and even now also works but after a while (I am guessing is not a matter of time but the amount of requests) and then fails,  all seems to be related to other causes and not with your code. It won't harm to check the server limits.